# how to find angle between two points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to find angle between two points(LatLong) in QGIS. For example

Point A = 80.2065,13.0876
Point B = 80.2064,13.0874

My CRS is WGS84 EPSG : 4326.

I am trying to provide driving direction this requires angle between points.

Comment: What do you mean by angle between two points? Do you mean bearing? If so, have a look at the formulae given on the following page: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe . Thank you so much. Article is useful. I found exact and brief answer from that article only.